# Can you have multiple sub-paths as a single path, and fill it just once?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I can render numerous particles (circles) by putting a `Path` in a `ForEach` and calling `.fill()` on each and every particle, like this:

```
struct Particles: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mainData: MainData

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<mainData.x.count, id: \.self) { i in
            Path { path in
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: mainData.x[i], y: mainData.y[i]), radius: CGFloat(mainData.size[i]), startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(360), clockwise: true)
            }
            .fill(mainData.colorForBrickParticles[i])
        }
    }
}
```

My assumption, however, is that it would be more performant to call `.fill()` on a single path instead of on many paths.

So, I tried iterating over my particles inside the `Path` and using `move(to:)` to create subpaths, then using a single `.fill()`, like this:

```
struct Particles: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mainData: MainData

    var body: some View {
        Path { path in
            for i in 0..<mainData.x.count {
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: mainData.x[i] + Double(mainData.size[i]), y: mainData.y[i]))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: mainData.x[i], y: mainData.y[i]), radius: CGFloat(mainData.size[i]), startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(360), clockwise: true)
            }
        }
        .fill(mainData.colorForBrickParticles[0])
    }
}
```

**But this doesn't work; the particles are not rendered using this strategy.**

How can I render multiple particles using a single `.fill()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create subpaths and add them to your path using `addPath`:

```
Path { path in
    for i in 0..<mainData.x.count {
        var subPath = Path()
        subPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: mainData.x[i], y: mainData.y[i]), radius: CGFloat(mainData.size[i]), startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(360), clockwise: true)
        path.addPath(subPath)
    }
}
.fill(mainData.colorForBrickParticles[0])
```